# NextJS & Vercel: Website not rendering/using CSS & ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

Our business is currently exploring **Vercel** to deploy our new landing pages written in **React & NextJS**. When running them locally (yarn dev) everything works correctly (both css imports and React hooks). When deployed on Vercel, both **CSS & React are not working**.

**Project is organized as follows (conceptually):**

- *./src/pages/_app.tsx*: Imports css (uses tailwind as well) and wraps app into IconContext.Provider (for icons)
- *./src/pages/index.tsx*: Exports (default) component, which uses inside react components to render / hooks to handle logic

We've spent the last few hours debugging this issue, but still no clue on where's the error (since we can perfectly launch them locally).

*You can have a look at the website here*: https://fudeo-flutter-advanced-git-master.aleamakers.vercel.app/

Can you understand **where's the error**? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running `yarn build && yarn start` - `yarn dev` is only a dev instance. - Additionally, what does the vercel dashboard show?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved and found the "error": I'm a complete idiot and React was working in reality. I though the opposite because of the missing css, which made everything messy.

The error I had was in purgecss: It had incorrect rules for purging css, and It was eliminating, at build time, all the custom css.

Thanks @Ramakay for your help. Actually using yarn build && yarn start made everything simpler to replicate locally (didn't notice them in the package.json).